# floating point rounding errors

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

The output is

```
x=1000300  y=1000000,  z=1000300
```

I can understand how I got x and z but <s>c's</s> y's output makes no sense.

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
 int main() 
 { int i=0; 
  float a = 100; 
  a = a*a*a*a*a;  

 float c = 3; 
 float x = 1000000*c + a; 
 float y = a; 
 float z = 0; 

  for (i=0; i<1000000; i++) 
  { y += c; 
    z += c; 
  } 

  z += a; 
  x /= 10000; 
  y /= 10000; 
  z /= 10000; 

 printf("x=%.0f  y=%.0f,  z=%.0f\n", x, y, z); 
 }
```

Comment: Am I missing something? Where is c's output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value in `y` starts out at 1E10 (from the assignment to `a`).  You add 3 to this a million times.

The trouble is that a `float` has at most 7 significant decimal digits, so you effectively do not change `y` each time, hence the result divided by 10,000 is <s>10,000,000</s> 1,000,000 as displayed.

If you coded it with `double`, you would see more nearly the result you expect.

Comment: Thank you for explanation though isn't y = 1,000,000?

Comment: @Mateo - yes - I can't count zeroes.  There are reasons why commas are used, and exponential notation.  I'll fix my answer.  (I should know that 1E10 / 1E4 == 1E6 too; I was careless.)